# SSMS Temp Table / Parameter Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I have a temp table with 2 columns, each column is a parameter I've declared. I've done so using this sql.

```
Declare  
@SourceKey varchar(40) = '1109'
,@Department Key varchar(1500) = '14,55
```

The table is then populated using the following sql:

```
if OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Department','U') is not null
    drop table #Department  
CREATE TABLE #Department
    (DepartmentKey int
    ,BaseTerm varchar(5))
INSERT INTO #Department
SELECT value
,skt.Key from YYY.ParseList(@Department,',')
join #SourceKeyTable skt
    on skt.Key = skt.key
```

If I `select * From #Department` I get these results:

```
Department Key | SourceKey
14             |   1109
55             |   1109
```

Thats what I expect. I then join the temp table to my main query like so

```
JOIN #Department d
        on Table.rKey = d.DepartmentKey
```

I need to have a temp table to allow for a multi-select in the visual studio report. However, with the department key equal to 14 **AND** 55 its skewing my results. I need 1 value passed 14 **OR** 55 not both. But the temp table is neccessary for the multi-select.

Any suggestions on how to pass only 1 value while still having set up mentioned previously? 

I'll do my best to answer questions as I might not have explained this question well enough for some.

Comment: You need the same query for two separate executions? One for 14 and one for 55?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I plan to execute the query once but pass 14 alone and then pass 55 as it's looped through the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you need to parse your list into a temporary table or table variable and then do whatever needs to be done with it.

It's difficult to see from your code exactly what that would involve but the code below should illustrate the idea sufficiently.

I create a table variable. Insert the parsed list values and then cycle through them printing the values to output

```
--Create a table variable
DECLARE @Departments TABLE(DepartmentOrder int identity, RKey nvarchar(40) NOT NULL)

--Create variables to loop through table variable
DECLARE @DepartmentOrder int
DECLARE @RKey nvarchar(40) 

--Populate table variable with the parsed list values
INSERT @Departments (RKey) SELECT RKey from YYY.ParseList(@Department,',')

--Get the first list entry
SELECT @DepartmentOrder  = min(DepartmentOrder ) FROM @Departments

--While we've not reached the end 
WHILE @DepartmentOrder  IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    --Get the Department key for this entry
    SET @RKey  = (SELECT RKey FROM @Departments WHERE DepartmentOrder   = @DepartmentOrder  ) 

    --Use the values
    PRINT '@DepartmentOrder  = '+CONVERT(nvarchar(9),@DepartmentOrder )
    PRINT '@RKey  = '''+@RKey  +''''

    --Get the next list entry
    SET @DepartmentOrder  = (SELECT MIN(DepartmentOrder ) FROM @Departments WHERE DepartmentOrder  > @DepartmentOrder )
END
```

Comment: I tried to recreate what you've posted. While I was able to get most of it built and able to work, do you mind adding a small example of the output that would be received from running: `` 'SELECT @DepartmentOrder  = MIN(DepartmentOrder ) FROM @Departments WHERE DepartmentOrder  > @DepartmentOrder' ``

Comment: SELECT @ DepartmentOrder = MIN(DepartmentOrder ) 
FROM @ Departments 
WHERE DepartmentOrder > @ DepartmentOrder

Doesn't produce output. 
It assigns a new value to the xDepartmentOrder variable

Note that I've had to put spaces after the @ symbol to post this

Comment: SET @ DepartmentOrder = (SELECT MIN(DepartmentOrder ) FROM @ Departments WHERE DepartmentOrder > @ DepartmentOrder )

Would work just as well and might be less confusing

I've changed the code above to use that